# angular-meteor $scope=collection.subscribe does not bind/refresh correctly

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angularjs-scope, angular-meteor

meteor, meteor & angular gurus.

I am really new to angular-meteor and facing the following problem. I perform a search using

```
$scope.Contacts = $meteor.collection(Contacts,false).subscribe('searchString', $scope.searchString);
```

or

```
$scope.Contacts = $scope.$meteorCollection(Contacts,false).subscribe('searchString', $scope.searchString);
```

and the `$scope.Contacts` does not refresh. It seems like its holds the old collection (speculation). I can see the data being returned by the mongo server and they look fine.If I iterate through the collection using $meteor.foreach you can see that the data are there.

But once the first search result is assigned to `$scope.Contacts` it wont refresh any more. I am having the feeling that `$scope.Contacts` keeps its own "collection" and only append new rows/docs coming from `$meteor.collection`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks All,

Sotiris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of weird. From my understanding, `subscribe` is linking the data pipline, `collections` is the representative of the data.

```
$scope.meteorSubscribe('contacts');
$scope.contacts = $scope.$meteorCollection(function (){
  Contacts.find({someField: $scope.searchString})
}
```

You might want something like this?